# Set the exact file name while downloading the files

Tags: java, spring, file

I’m trying to download a file and, dynamically, I’m setting the file name. But while downloading the file I’m receiving the file name as "3823720b-3d63-4e2c-8fc2-6abdc34b5cd8.docx" But I’m passing my file name as "Sample.docx"

```
 if (Files.exists(file)) {
            response.setContentType(existingDocuments.getContentType());
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + existingDocuments.getFileName());
            Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
```

Comment: existingDocuments.getFileName() is this the value as "Sample.docx"

Comment: You are somehow missing a question here.

Comment: @jai Yes there is no querstion in the statement made.

Comment: Please give more information on your code. So that it might be helpful

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the question, Can you answer me now?

Comment: You did not add a question, you just removed some words...

Comment: @Ben Yes, i have updated only the question name. You cannot able to understand my question ???

Comment: @amRika You are right, existingDocuments.getFileName() is the value of  "Sample.docx"!

Comment: How do you know you’re getting into the “if” and what happens when you don’t?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo That's business logic. if file was null, i can't download anything. Am just throwing exception.

Comment: @jai You seem to check `if(Files.exist(file))`, but your header is based on some other variable `existingDocuments.getFilename()`. Why not `files.getFilename()`? What exactly does that other variable contains?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo 'existingDocuments.getFileName()' contains Sample.docx. Do you have any issue on that?

Comment: @jai Not really, but it is not obvious in your code where `existingDocuments` comes from, so it was a potential source of the issue. That’s why I asked. From my perspective, besides the lack of apostrophes already mentioned in an answer, I don’t seem to find anything wrong with your code. Chances are the cause of the problem is not in the snippet that you’re sharing with us.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
response.header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileNameDisplay + "\"");
```

you might also need to add

response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

Comment: I have tried that too. Didn't worked for me. Still am facing the same

Comment: instead of using Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream()); try copying raw bytes by code. I used this outputStream.write(bytesReadFromFile[]));

Comment: Did you find anything wrong with [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream))? Otherwise this final suggestion is just [shotgun debugging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging).

Comment: I have tried content type as application/octet-stream too. But getting same issue

Comment: ideally it should shouldn't, can you try to replace existingDocuments.getFileName() with saple.docx and see if it works. This same code is working for me in one project so it should work for you too.

Comment: Really thanks for your valuable tries. I have tried in that way too :-(

Comment: just to test can you try removing response.getOutputStream().flush();

Comment: @techtrainer but the flush statement is required to push the data from the stream into the file. Do you think it may cause that issue?

Comment: @amRika I have similar solution and it doesn't use flushing and it working fine and has passed extreme performance tests. Is your assumption based on any documentation?